# Highlight function name in Vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I've tried to set highlight syntax pattern in my syntax file for vim, but I've failed. Is there an eny option to match function's name when we assume that every function's name starts with "f_" and ends with "("?

I've already tried something like this:
`syn match abcFunc /f_*/`,
but it has highlighted only "f" or "f_"... Any ideas?

Comment: read about the regex syntax.

Comment: Do you mind give an explanation why this work?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
syn match Function /\<f_[^(]*(/he=e-1
```